# When do you want more/less http requests?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, http

It seems like to have you page load fast, you would want a series of small http requests.

If it was one big one, the user might have to wait much longer to see that the page was there at all.

However, I'v heard that minimizing your HTTP requests is more efficient.  For example, this is why sprites are created for multiple images.

Is there a general guideline for when you want more and when you want less?

Comment: I didn't really get why there was a downvote on this question - some people think just about **everything** is trivial I guess :(

Comment: Go look on any web site an you will see there are many initial requests that could easily be consolidated by using a build system.  So the answers don't match up to reality.

Comment: There are many cases when you need smaller but more requests, user interaction is 1 b.c. it is not an option.  Also, for initial page load, I think a small packet is good, to get some visualization in front of the user fast. Give them some indication that the main "blob" is loading.

Comment: for lack of guidance, the [google page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) can provide you much information. Point it at some sites you know, and it will analyse the site and make recommendations. The gist of it is : number of requests is important, but also `when` you issue requests, the payload nature, the target devices, audience, etc ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT 2 (25-08-2017)

Another update here; Some time has passed and [HTTP2](https://http2.github.io/) is (becoming) a real thing. I suggest reading [this page](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/charter/) for more information about it.

Taken from the second link (at the time of this edit):

> It is expected that HTTP/2.0 will:
>
> Substantially and measurably improve end-user perceived latency in
>   most cases, over HTTP/1.1 using TCP. Address the "head of line
>   blocking" problem in HTTP.
>
> **Not require multiple connections to a server to enable parallelism,
>   thus improving its use of TCP, especially regarding congestion
>   control.**
>
> Retain the semantics of HTTP/1.1, leveraging existing documentation
>   (see above), including (but not limited to) HTTP methods, status
>   codes, URIs, and where appropriate, header fields.
>
> Clearly define how HTTP/2.0 interacts with HTTP/1.x, especially in
>   intermediaries (both 2->1 and 1->2).
>
> Clearly identify any new extensibility points and policy for their
>   appropriate use.

The bold sentence (emphasis mine) explains how HTTP2 will handle requests differently from HTTP1. Whereas HTTP1 will create ~8 (differs per browser) simultaneous (or "parallel") connections to fetch as much resources as possible, HTTP2 will re-use the same connection. This reduces overall time and network latency required to create a new connection which in turn, speeds up asset delivery. Additionally, your webserver will also have an easier time keeping ~8 times less connections open. Imagine the gains there :)

HTTP2 is also already quite widely supported in major browsers, [caniuse has a table for it](http://caniuse.com/#search=http2) :)

### EDIT (30-11-2015)

I've recently found [this article](http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/) on the topic 'page speed'. this post is very thorough and it's an interesting read at worst so I'd definitely give it a shot.

---

### Original

There are too many answers to this question but here's my 2cents.

If you want to build a website you'll need few basic things in your tool belt like HTML, CSS, JS - maybe even PHP / Rails / Django (or one of the 10000+ other web frameworks) and MySQL.

The front-end part is basically all that gets sent to the client every request. The server-sided language calculates what needs to be sent which is how you build your website.

Now when it comes to managing assets (images, CSS, JS) you're diving into HTTP land since you'll want to do as few requests as possible. The reason for this is that there is a [DNS penalty](https://gtmetrix.com/minimize-dns-lookups.html).

This DNS penalty however does not dictate your entire website of course. It's all about the balance between amount of requests and read- / maintainability for the programmers building the website.

Some frameworks like rails allow you to combine all your JS and CSS files into a big *meta-like* JS and CSS file before you deploy your application on your server. This ensures that (unless done otherwise) for instance **ALL** the **JS** and **ALL** the **CSS** used in the website get sent in one request per file.

Imagine having a popup script and something that fetches articles through AJAX. These will be two different scripts and when deploying without combining them - each page load including the popup and article script will send two requests, one for each file respectively.

The reason this is not true is because browsers cache whatever they can whenever they can because in the end browsers and people who build websites want the same thing. The best experience for our users!
This means that during the **first** request your website will ever answer to a client will cache as **much as possible** to make consecutive page loads faster in the future.

This is kind of like the browser way of helping websites become faster.
Now when the brilliant browserologists think of something it's more or less our job to make sure it works for the browser. Usually these sorts of things with caching etc are trivial and not hard to implement (thank god for that).

Having a lot of HTTP requests in a page load isn't an end-of-the-world thing since it'll only slow your first request but overall having less requests makes this "DNS-penalty" thing appear less often and will give your users more of an instant page load.

There are also other techniques besides file-merging that you could use to your advantage, when including a javascript you can choose it to be [*async* or *defer*](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html).

For async it means the script will be loaded and executed in the background whenever it's loaded, regardless of order of inclusion within HTML. This also pauses the HTML parser to execute the script directly.

For defer it's a bit different. It's kind of like async but files *will* be executed in the correct order and only **after** the HTML parser is done.

Something you wouldn't want to be "async" would be *jQuery* for instance, it's the key library for a lot of websites and you'll want to use it in other scripts so using async and not being sure when it's downloaded and executed is not a good plan.

Something you would want to be "async" is a google analytics script for instance, it's effectively optional for the end-user and thus should be labelled as not important - no matter how much you care about the stats your website isn't built **for** you but **by** you :)

To get back to requests and blend all this talk about async and deferred together, you can have multiple JS on your page for instance and not have the HTML parser pause to execute some JS - instead you can make this script *defer* and you'll be fine since the user's HTML and CSS will load while the JS parser waits nicely for the HTML parser.

This is not an example of reducing HTTP requests but it is an example of an alternative solution should you have this "one file" that doesn't really belong anywhere except in a separate request.

You will also never be able to build a perfect website, nor will http://github.com or http://stackoverflow.com but it doesn't matter, they are fast enough for our eyes to not see any crazy flashing content and *those* things are truly important for end-users.

If you are curious about how much requests is normal - don't. It's different for every website and the purpose of the website, tho I agree some things do go over the top sometimes but it is what it is and all we have to do is support browsers like they are supporting us - Even looking at IE / Edge there since they are also improving (slowly but steady anyways).

I hope my story made sense to you, I did re-read before the post but couldn't find anything while scouting for irregular typing or other kinds of illogical things.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very thorough, I think it's definitely not as simple as the less requests the better.  There needs to be a strategy, and you outlined much of that.

Comment: @cadegalt it's definitely more complicated than less is more indeed but the balance for that is always tricky to find and *that* is what the answer is all about here, good luck :)

Comment: Forums are a good example of websites where speed doesn't matter so long as it doesn't break usability, people are less tolerant towards blogs taking a long time, and least tolerant towards websites they've never visited before unless they know what content to expect.  This is why most landing pages out there are highly optimized while the rest of the site tends to relax a bit in favour of maintainability.

Comment: @Flosculus I get your point but it also depends on the audience you're targetting, the folks @ SO will tolerate even outage without raging because we simply have the decency to be constructive under all circumstances whereas a user on FB has no idea how or why an outage occurs: **_hackers? annoying - fend em off pl0x_**

Comment: Is the DNS penalty still applicable? The title on that website now says "PageSpeed: Minimize DNS lookups (**deprecated**)".

Comment: @kiradotee while it isn't explained in the article, it could be that this is because of the HTTP2 spec, where multiple "requests" (for single files) can be bundled and sent as a single request. If properly done, the DNS penalty will probably never even be reached. -- I am just guessing tho, the reason isn't stated and my comment is merely a possibility, I hope you'll find the real answer!

Answer (score 7):

Multiple requests create overhead from both the connection and the headers.

Its like downloading the contents of an FTP site, one site has a single 1GB blob, another has 1,000,000 files totalling a few MB.  On a good connection, the 1GB file could be downloaded in a few minutes, but the other is sure to take all day because the transfer negotiation ironically takes more time that the transfer itself.

HTTP is a bit more efficient than FTP, but the principle is the same.
What is important is the initial page load, which needs to be small enough to show some content to the user, then load additional assets outside of the user's view.  A page with a thousand tiny images will benefit from a sprite always because the negotiations would not only cause strain to the connection, but also potentially the client computer.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol is verbose, so the ratio of header size to payload size makes it more efficient to have a larger payload. On top of that, this is still a distributed communication which makes it inherently slow. You also, usually, have to set up and tear down the TCP connection for each request.

Also, I have found, that the small requests repeat data between themselves in an attempt to achieve RESTful purity (like including user data in every response).

The only time small requests are useful is when the data may not be needed at all, so you only load it when needed. However, even then it may be more performant to.simply retrieve it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You always want less requests.

The reason we separate any javascript/css code in other files is we want the browser to cache them so other pages on our website will load faster.
If we have a single page website with no common libraries (like jQuery) it's best if you include all the code in your html.

Comment: Not really true. It's always better to separate HTML, JS and CSS. If you have them all in the HTML and you do one small change in one of the three, you need to reload everything. I think for a small page, it should be at least one of each for caching purposes.

Comment: You're talking about a case that I have already excluded: where you want the browser to cache the js/css for you :)

Comment: True. But it does apply to one-page-websites as well since the user might reload the page, or re-visit it later. ;-) But yes. If you don't want the browser to cache the page at all, then you can put it all in one file.